# Search Google with a date/time range

Tags: google-search, date

I want to restrict Google search to a specific date/time range. How can this be done?

Comment: I'm afraid your question makes no sense. How does one "run Google" much less with an "older date"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are asking how to perform a Google search with a time value flag on the search.

This can be done by your program building its own search url.  You likely already know that the searched string appears after the `q=` flag in the url.  For time based searches you add the `tbs=qdr:` flag followed by the time period value you wish to use. Some of the possible values you can use are:

- `a` for *any time*
- `n` for **

  - Add a number after n to tell Google how many minutes (i.e. `tbs=qdr:n15` for the last 15 minutes)
- `h` for *hour*

  - Add a number after h to tell Google how many minutes (i.e. `tbs=qdr:h3` for the last 3 hours)
- `d` for *day*
- `w` for *week*
- `m` for *month*
- `y` for *year*

Example: http://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=querystring&tbs=qdr:d will search for *querystring* and return results that are dated in the last day.

You can also specify a date range using `tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:xx/xx/xxxx,cd_max:xx/xx/xxxx`.